# Redirection isn't working in Wordpress Azure

Tags: wordpress, azure, redirect, subdomain, domain-name

I recently installed my wordpress website in Azure, but for some reason the redirection plugin that i installed in wordpress does not seem to work or take any effect.

I'm trying to redirect my blog posts to my subdomain, i used various wordpress plugins for the redirection but none of them seem to show any results.

If anyone have any suggestions or know how to deal with this particular problem it will be much appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Try this plugin https://wordpress.org/plugins/seo-redirection/. This will help.

Comment: Thanks. But for some reason when i installed this plugin and accessed the plugin's settings i get the following errors: [Table 'rob_public.wor_wp_seo_redirection' doesn't exist] [Table 'rob_public.wor_wp_seo_redirection' doesn't exist] Any idea why i'm getting this error ?

Comment: As you tried lots of plugins, just delete all others and then re-install this one. If no success you must go with their support forum https://wordpress.org/support/plugin/seo-redirection/

Comment: Thank you man for your help and follow up. Indeed there was something wrong with the plugin, it was not creating the tables necessary for the plugin to work. However from all the plugins i tried, this is the only one that worked https://wordpress.org/plugins/simple-301-redirects/   i wonder why, i would like to know the cause though !